# Nodejs setInterval() with mongo query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, setinterval, scheduler

I'm currently developing a toy project about hotel reservation and I need to register the amount of days a room will be in use, I was required to use mongodb so my first approach to this was using setInterval() to query the database and see if the rooms time limit had expired (we are talking about a small amount of rooms about 40~60) my question is, is this a bad approach? would it create too big of a load on the database unnecessarily?(if let's say it was a big hotel or chain of hotels with thousands of rooms) 
is there a more efficient alternative? 
And if this one is viable, which would you consider would be a good interval to set?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you describe a toy project but try to ask about real-world problems. The answer would probably be: it depends. What is "too big of a load"? What response time do you want? What server resources do you have? I'm afraid there's no reasonable answer unless you have a real case. And probably when you do, you will either have no issues with your approach or will return here and ask a good question, which others will be happy to help you sovling.

Comment: How often is your `setInterval()` querying the database or does it need to query?  Once a day is no big deal.  Hundreds of times a minute is a big deal.  This frequency and scale determines whether you need a different solution (such as an in-memory array of expiration dates).

Comment: @YakovL it's a toy project for me, but I'm trying to learn through it which is why I want to know how it would affect in a real world problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 well the rooms will be taken for a minimum of 1day so I was thinking somewhere along the  lines of 2-5 minutes, less if possible.

Comment: Is that doing 60 queries (one for each room) every 2-5 minutes?  Or one query every 2-5 minutes?  Repeated querying of the database on short intervals is NEVER the best way to solve this type of problem.  The question is whether you can get away with it for the specifics of your project.  So, you would never want to do it the way you're proposing for a large scale project.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was thinking 1 query to bring all the rooms and process the rest server-side and then only updating those that expired, for my project this would solve it, but even with just 1 query is it still not viable? if so, how should I go about it?

Comment: You'll have to test your own project to see if that is viable.  There's probably nothing wrong with a query every few minutes if the query isn't too expensive and you have appropriate database tech.  I was just explaining that frequent polling/querying isn't a large scale solution which you also seemed to be asking about.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see, thanks a lot :)